# Gauss law for gravitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, gauss-law

> Assume earth as a solid sphere of radius R with volume mass density K varies with radial distance as $P = P_or$. A tunnel is dug along the radius up to a depth $R/2$ and a body is projected from the bottom of the tunnel, so that it escapes from earth gravity. Find the velocity of projection.

[image]

For doing this I had tried using gauss law for gravitation, so I wrote the following equation-

$$
E(4\pi x^2) = 4\pi G(M)\ ---(1)
$$

Where $x$ is the distance from centre of the sphere. Now for $M$ I integrated the following equation-
$$
M = \int P_o4\pi x^2dx
$$
which gave $M= (4\pi P_o x^4)/4$. Substituting that into equation 1 we get-
$$
E= (\pi GP_ox^2)/---(2)
$$
From here I used the fact that the potential= integration of $-E.dx$, so I integrated equation 2 to find potential at $R/2$ and $R$, for **$R/2$ I got $(\pi GP_oR^3)/24$ and for $R$ I got $(\pi GP_oR^3)/3$.** Then I got the potential difference as
$$
(7\pi GP_oR^3)/24\ ---(3)
$$
and then multiplying it with with the mass of particle, i.e $m$, and equating it to the kinetic energy, I got the velocity as
$$
V = \sqrt{(7\pi GP_oR^3)/12}.$$
The answer given is
$$
\sqrt{(31G\pi P_oR)/12}.
$$
What did I miss here? Or is there anything else I need to know about this concept? And I would highly appreciate learning a new technique for solving these type of problems.